# Specific view not opening on notification tap when app is terminated

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on push notifications in `Xamarin.Forms` using [**`Plugin.FirebasePushNotification`**](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin). Notifications are not opening specific view when app terminated(killed from taskbar).

When app open or in background, I am able to navigate to specific page when clicking on notification.
This is Application class

```
public class AppClass : Android.App.Application, Android.App.Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
{
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this,false,true);
        var instanceid = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
    }
}
```

MainActivity class

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    LoadApplication(new App());
}

protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);
    FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, intent);
}
```

App.xaml.cs class in shared project

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += (s, p) =>
    {
        if (p.Data.ContainsKey("color"))
        {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page1()
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex($"{p.Data["color"]}")
            });
        });
        }
    };
}
```

This is payload I am sending from *Postman*

```
{ 
 "to":"dhNe4U_jSDo:APA91bHhupDfnqW5Y9EBIfWV-uQVmq_HyPXTzBZ_TnSfM-7cDEq8SUFDLeudA4vWzyMj28E8A_c5HS0F2f5xT8quWZHcmWL8RJEbeDNre3RMsuY7brcAxqQMQOMCDcVXWDsl7s15l-NC", 
 "notification" : {
 "body" : "New announcement assigned",
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "max",
 "color":"Page1",
 "content_available" : true,
 "title": "notification TITLE",
 "content_available" : true,
 "body": "notification BODY",
 },
 "data" : {
 "OrganizationId":"2",
 "color":"Page1",
 "click_action":"MainActivity"
 "sectionId":"33",
 "priority" : "high",
 "title": "notification TITLE",
 "content_available" : true,
 "body": "notification BODY",
}
}
```

This is my menifest class

```
<application android:label="FCMPush.Android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <receiver
      android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" 
      android:exported="false" />
    <receiver
          android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
          android:exported="true"
          android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
          <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>      
    </receiver>
</application>
```

I have assigned [this issue](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/issues/197) on GitHub as well. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by `when app in foreground(killed from taskbar)`? An app in  foreground means  the user is working on the app instead of killed from taskbar.

Comment: Oh! I thought when app in foreground is totally closed. Is this state called background? Thank you.

Comment: Basically, background means the app is still running in the background. You can call the state `terminated` when the app is killed from taskbar.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. You can help me out if you have developed notification using this plugin in xamarin.forms.

Comment: Since your app is killed by taskbar, I guess this is caused by your app is not ready when you tap the notification. I mean maybe the `OnNotificationOpened` function code haven't been read at the point you tap the notification. It is different when your app is in background and foreground.

Comment: @jackHua - I tried keeping `OnNotificationOpened` on various places including android & shared project, still same issue. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that you misused `click_action`. 1. It needs to be under `notification`. 2. As per the docs "*If specified, an activity **with a matching intent filter** is launched when a user clicks on the notification.*"

Comment: @AL. - I tried various combinations as you said, but it doesn't seems to be working. Xamarin.Forms has different way of development unlike android, I think.

Comment: So it would seem. I'm not entirely sure, but I remember there was a specific format for the value in `click_action`. I haven't tested this in a while. Could you try adding exact location of the activity (e.g. `com.sample.Activity`) -- like what I did to my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464172/4625829)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am not really sure where the issue might be. However, if we take a look at the docs: https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md, there are several things that you can try.

First of all set `Exported = true` and `LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop` in your `MainActivity`. **Also** set `FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);` in your `onCreate()`, right after `LoadApplication(new App());`.

**Note that as of Android 8.0, you have to set `DefaultNotificationChannelId` and `DefaultNotificationChannelName` in your Application's `onCreate()` as well.**

Then, if you have a `SplashActivity`, make sure you add `MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true` to it, and the following code in `onCreate()`:

```
var mainIntent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity));

 if (Intent.Extras != null) {
     mainIntent.PutExtras(Intent.Extras);
 }
 mainIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
 StartActivity(mainIntent);
```

I would also recommend you to take a look at the following folder of the repo: https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/tree/master/samples/FirebasePushSample/FirebasePushSample.Android. If you carefully follow all code, it should work.

Comment: I was missing this `FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);`. It's working now. You pointed out few things than I paid more attention. Luckily you got bounty. :)

Comment: Good to hear :)

Comment: My case was I set enableDelayedResponse to false, FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent, enableDelayedResponse:false);, fixed by set enableDelayedResponse back to true(as it is by default)

Answer (score 0):

if your having, splash activity before Main activity, then send the push info to main activity on resume, sample below:

```
protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
        startupWork.Start();
    }

    // Simulates background work that happens behind the splash screen
    async void SimulateStartup()
    {

        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        if (Intent.Extras != null)
        {
            intent.PutExtras(Intent.Extras); // copy push info from splash to main
        }
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
```

in the new intent method of the main activity, you can get the details. sample below,

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);

        var type = intent.GetStringExtra("type");
        if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(type) && object.Equals(type, "notification")))
        {
            // do your logic

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When app is killed or not in background then in that case OnNewIntent Mentod is not called. it is called only when the existing screen is in background(i.e already existing intent is in background) and you fire a new intent to bring that screen forward.(I may have not used the correct technical words, just trying to explain the concept)

In your case OnCreate is called as the app is not in background so you need to handle it from there,

Try moving the process intent call below the LoadApplication method in oncreate.

Ex:

```
LoadApplication(new App());
FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this,Intent)
```

-- OR --

I would suggest parse the intent in OnCreate method and pass the necessary information as parameters to the APP class via constructor whenever a notification is clicked.

Ex.: `LoadApplication(new App('imp data that you want'));`

From App class then you can navigate user to anywhere you want without disturbing the back stack of the application.

Comment: Check the edited answer, let me know if it works.

writing a sample code right now is not possible for me.